# Jmeter connection reset by Peer: socket write error/ socket exception: connection reset

Tags: performance, testing, file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a performance test that is running in jmeter on a win7 machine.

The performance test is comprised of 2 threads groups( user1, user2) and each thread makes 40 requests to a website using http request modules.

**Test layout:** 
2 threads groups each containing 40 requests ( including 5 file uploads),cookie manager.

I ran this test with 50 threads on each thread group and I keep getting errors.

***Error Stack trace:***

**Error 1** - `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:169)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:97)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$ViewableFileBody.writeTo(HTTPHC4Impl.java:896)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:206)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:224)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

**Error 2** - `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

When I run the test at 25 threads I don't get these Errors.`enter code here`

I have tried to change settings in the properties file and I have also tried adding:
**set IPV4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true and set ARGS=%DUMP% %HEAP% %NEW% %SURVIVOR% %TENURING% %PERM% %DDRAW% %IPV4%** to jmeter.bat but I still get the errors..

Please help..What could cause these errors? How do I fix them?  any help is greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Are you running this against a localhost:port service on the Win7 machine? If it's a remote machine, does it have a limit to the number of connections it serves before it stops allowing more?

Comment: I might as well indicate that you reached the server's limit. See the server side logs. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228533/342862) answer in a different question.

Comment: In other words, I don't think it's a local JMeter problem, it's your server that probably reached it's limit, or something in-between. Tune your server.

Comment: Try to re-run your test after changing the "Implementation" to "JAVA" for all HTTP Samplers.

Comment: Very important:  what is the "ramp up time" in your test suite?  Are you sure your not starting all the threads simultaneously, which may cause contention issues?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're suffering from the situation highlighted in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) Wiki article.

> If you upgraded recently to JMeter 2.10 or 2.11, you may have noticed increased errors of this type:
>
> Socket closed
>
> Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException (the target server failed to respond)

In order to make these errors go away

- Make sure that your HTTP Requests "Implementation" is HTTPClient4
- Add the following lines to *user.properties* file (located in /bin folder of your JMeter home)

  ```
  httpclient4.retrycount=1
  hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
  ```

  3. In the `hc.parameters` file (same location - JMeter's /bin folder) uncomment the next line:

     http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

For more information on various useful JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Are this suggestions still relevant to JMeter 3.3?

Comment: I had same issue in jmeter 4.0 which is resolved with this solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and thought there was some changes needed on jmeter configuration. However, the issue was with my request header. There was an empty header row that was causing this error.

I removed the empty row and that solved the issue. So, please check the raw request from jmeter and compare it with a working request from postman or any other http client to make sure you're sending the valid request

Answer (score 0):

In Client Implementation, select Implementation as Java. Worked for me.