# JMeter - Connection reset and SSL errors when load test more than 120 threads in windows 7

Tags: multithreading, sockets, ssl, jmeter

I'm trying to load test website with latest JMeter 3.3 from windows 7/10

When threads are 120 or above I start getting SSL handshakes failures from F5.

When I add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to execution I found many different socket exceptions as:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
```

Or

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
```

Or

```
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
```

I follow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563156/jmeter-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-write-error-socket-exception-connectio), but it may be outdated:

> Make sure that your HTTP Requests "Implementation" is HTTPClient4 Add
>   the following lines to user.properties file (located in /bin folder of
>   your JMeter home)
>
> httpclient4.retrycount=1 hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters In the
>   hc.parameters file (same location - JMeter's /bin folder) uncomment
>   the next line:
>
> http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

How can prevent those errors? I tried adjusting ramp up period but it didn't helped.
I also tried adding EnableConnectionRateLimiting registry suggested [here](https://www.technorms.com/24822/disable-max-limit-set-simultaneous-network-connections) and failed.

Did I reach the limit to JMeter on windows or can it be configured/increased?

**EDIT**

I tried setting HTTP with different retry count and with Java implementation but no change.

**EDIT2**

I found that using specific proper TLSv1.2 protocol for my HTTP Request fixed the issue, in jmeter.properties add the line:

```
https.socket.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

There was [enhancement](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54759) for make http parameters configurable.

This enable me to increase load up to ~220 threads without SSL handshake errors in the ramp up period.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK we did a workaround to overcome it

Comment: what was it if not confidential?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK didn't pass through F5

Comment: So it was a performance issue of F5 ? I already met this kind of issue also with it. Sometimes also it was a keepalive mistmatch.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK it seems to be F5 issue

Answer (score 1):

You may need to adjust windows tcp settings to avoid reaching opened port limits.

See this:

- https://www.filehold.com/help/technical/Windows-Server-Tuning-to-Prevent-TCPIP-Port-Exhaustion

You need to set:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995661.aspx
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397379.aspx
  Windows 2003
  Reduce the TIME_WAIT by setting the TcpTimedWaitDelay TCP/IP parameter to 30 seconds on the windows registry key
- HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, as a DWORD value.
  Increase the range of ephemeral ports by setting the MaxUserPort TCP/IP parameter to an higher value (like 32768), on the windows registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, as a DWORD value. This will set the port range from 1024 to 32768.
- Windows 2008 R2
  Reduce the TIME_WAIT by setting the TcpTimedWaitDelay TCP/IP parameter to 30 seconds on the windows registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, as a DWORD value.
  Increase the range of ephemeral ports by setting the dynamicportrange to an higher value through the command netsh int ipv4 set dynamicportrange tcp start=32767 num=65535, this will set the port range from 32768 to 65535.

Comment: Those are Windows Server tuning tips, are they relevant ?

Comment: I updated answer, in my experience with windows you need to set those registry values on windows depending on version