# JMeter 5.3 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error messages

Tags: sockets, exception, jmeter, socketexception

I use JMeter 5.3 for load testing of a web application and SAML authentication. I execute JMeter with use of `jmeter.bat` file. Application backend is configured properly, but I get following error message:

> Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
> Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

I use `http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true` parameter in user.properties file.

I set connection timeout to `4000 ms` in each HTTP requests. First error message appears in less than 4 seconds, when test is started.
SSL certificates are not self-signed.

**UPDATE:**
I increased pool size for TCP connections, but problem still persists.

```
Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name MaxUserPort -Value 65534 -Force | Out-Null
Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name TcpTimedWaitDelay -Value 30 -Force | Out-Null
Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name TcpNumConnections -Value 16777214 -Force | Out-Null
Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name TcpMaxDataRetransmissions -Value 5 -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: Do you use distributed testing ? probably issue with windows maximum connections, similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902427/jmeter-connection-reset-and-ssl-errors-when-load-test-more-than-120-threads-in

Comment: @user7294900 : It is running on Windows Server 2012. Are those relevant for this OS?

Comment: you can check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9647a3c4-49df-4e40-a981-50e6d9c23c8a/limit-of-concurrent-tcp-connections-for-2012-essential?forum=winserveressentials

Comment: @user7294900 : I just updated values, but exceptions are still present during execution. I've updated also my question.